# Should we split data across on-the-fly created tables in MySQL or go with other DBMS?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Current Design:

```
Table: users
------------------------------
| id | email                 |
------------------------------  
| 1  | abc@xyz.com           |
| 2  | def@mno.com           |
| 3  | fun@ton.com           |


Table: user_notes
-----------------------------------------------------
| id | user_id  | content     | created_at          |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1  |    1     | loreum ipsu | 2017-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 2  |    1     | loreum ipsu | 2017-01-02 11:00:00 |
| 3  |    2     | loreum ipsu | 2017-01-03 12:00:00 |
```

Proposed Design:

```
Table: users
------------------------------
| id | email                 |
------------------------------  
| 1  | abc@xyz.com           |
| 2  | def@mno.com           |
| 3  | fun@ton.com           |

Table: user_1_notes
------------------------------------------
| id | content     | created_at          |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | loreum ipsu | 2017-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 2  | loreum ipsu | 2017-01-02 11:00:00 |

Table: user_2_notes
------------------------------------------
| id | content     | created_at          |
|-----------------------------------------
| 1  | loreum ipsu | 2017-01-01 10:00:00 |
```

I am proposing this design because I have found that our MySQL server (1 
cpu 3.7GB Google CloudSQL) becomes horribly slow after ~100 million rows in `user_notes` table and also we can create almost 4 billion tables.

We can bump up the instance and that surely increase the performance but we don't have the budget. I have yet to run a performance test. But I think it's better to ask the expert community

- about the PROS and CONS of the above design.

Also, guide me if I had the budget then what could be the best way to achieve the same

- just bump up the MySQL server
- shift to other technology eg. Cloud Spanner, MongoDB etc.
- or other...

**UPDATED**

SLOW Query (1 min 23 sec)

```
SELECT * FROM user_tables WHERE user_id=2 AND DATE(created_at) >= '2017-01-01' AND DATE(created_at) < '2017-02-01'
```

NOTE:

- All my queries to user_notes table will be always like `WHERE user_id=XXX`
- I never have to query 2 or more users at the same time

Comment: Too many details are missing: types of queries you expect to execute, what "slow" means (we need numbers), what's your MySQL config (can it "eat" sufficient RAM), have you profiled your current queries etc. 
However... your proposed design is simply awful - there are no words to explain how bad it is. Zero gain, maximum convolution, splitting data in tables does N O T H I N G for performance. Now, you can go with some other db, sure. They aren't faster. It's a marketing ploy. Use what you know, time is your most expensive resource.

Comment: @N.B. I have updated slow query with notes. I don't know how MySQL works internally but I thought that If I have tables with lesser rows (~10,000) and I always have to query only that table it would be much faster as compared to table with many rows (~100,000,000). and thanks for your fast response :)

Comment: Can you show us the output of  `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM user_tables WHERE user_id=2 AND DATE(created_at) >= '2017-01-01' AND DATE(created_at) < '2017-02-01'` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_tables`?

Comment: @user2576951 Please POST results of A) EXPLAIN request from N.B. on 7/27/18, B) SHOW CREATE TABLE users;  C) SHOW CREATE TABLE user_notes;  D) SHOW INDEX FROM users;  E)  SHOW INDEX FROM user_notes; so we have a more complete picture of your FIRST and BEST design.  4 Billion tables in a single database would not be very desirable (or manageable).

Comment: If your quires are made all over the world you can benefit from [Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/). It has availability to scale horizontally across rows, regions, and continents,

Answer (score 4):

1.your Current Design is far better than the Proposed Design

2.My suggestion if you have budget then just bump up the MySQL server

3.I don't think for this purpose technology change would be the wise decesion

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index for `user_id`? Maybe you can start there.

The proposed design is probably not a good idea, either you use MySQL, MongoDB or some other solution.

On MongoDB, for instance, you should embed documents whenever possible, which means you would probably be better off with something like:

```
Collection: users
{
  id: 1,
  email: abc@xyz.com,
  notes: [
    {
      content: 'loreum ipsu',
      created_at: '2017-01-01 10:00:00'
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

And then, depending on the number of notes each user would have (probably a lot) you would have to be aware of the document size limit (16MB, last time I heard). So, maybe your current design might turn out to not be that bad.

If you end up going that route though, MySQL now also has a document store [offering](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/document-store.html) similar to MongoDB, however, I'm not sure if it is supported on Google Cloud (I don't think so). So, ultimately, maybe you don't need to "shift to other technology".

Disclaimer: I work at MySQL (but I'm not an expert on schema design)